# Using jquery post to get image generated by jpgraph

Tags: php, jquery, post, jpgraph

I have a page which is used to show a chart image generated by jpgraph.

This page contains folllowing script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.post('wr.php', function(data) {
var newImg = jQuery('<img />');
newImg.attr('src', data);   
jQuery('#placeholder').html(newImg);
});
});
```

Then th wr.php contains script to generate graph

```
<?php
//lines to generate chart data

$graph->Add($wp);

$contentType = 'image/png';
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);

ob_start();                        // start buffering
$graph->img->Stream();             // print data to buffer
$image_data = ob_get_contents();   // retrieve buffer contents
ob_end_clean();                    // stop buffer

echo "data:$contentType;base64;" . base64_encode($image_data);
?>
```

But the output I get in the page is only a red X mark. Any work around?

Comment: chrome developer tool shows "failed to load resource"

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag is supposed to be a URL for retrieving the image, not the actual data for the image itself. I don't see why you need an AJAX call for this at all, just try the following:

```
var newImg = jQuery('<img>', {src: 'wr.php'});
jQuery('#placeholder').empty().append(newImg);
```

Comment: ajax is needed because I want to send some data to the script wr.php so that chart is generated according to the data

Comment: What if I want to send some parameters to wr.php?

Comment: @mansoondreamz Then put them as parameters of the URL in the `src` tag, like so: `'wr.php?param1=value1&param2=value2'`. Right now your `jQuery.post()` doesn't have any data (parameters) though.

Comment: Right now I want to see the image without any parameters. Later on i want to send afew parameters.

Comment: @mansoondreamz Well, try it out then? AJAX isn't really intended for loading images, there's just no need for it. There's no page reload involved with setting the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element.

Comment: Your suggestion to add parameter to th URL is working. But echo would have much functionality. Since I do not want to bore the valued people here I have not given more details. In fact, the parameters passed will be used in constructing SQL to fetch data from mysql database. If there is no data corresponding the params, I can echo a friendly message instead of a blank page. If I use your suggestion , wr.php wll send either a chart image or a blank chart. No other data will be send